# How to add a column from a user input to the existing data frame?

Tags: r, dataframe, input

I am struggling with taking the input from the user and storing it as a vector and then adding it as a new column to the existing data frame.

```
df <- data.frame(aa1 = c("S", "K", "A", "A", "L", "D", "L", "E", "E", "H", "T", "D", "V", "V", "Q", "K", "K", "N", "A", "I", "E", "I", "V", "T", "L"),
                      aa2 = c("C","V","Q","W","K","N","A","Y","A","L","C","W","L","D","C","I","L","S","A","L","V","H","S","E","E")) 

read_aa <- function() {
  my_seq <- readline(prompt="Enter aa: ")
  aa3 <- strsplit(my_seq, "") #splitting aa into separate string
  df1 <- df
  df1 <- cbind(new_col = aa3, df) 
}
print(read_aa())
```

The example of the input: ALDIKSADPEVMLLTLSLYKQLNNN 
To note, I would be grateful for tips on how to store the input into the separate column for each time the user enters a new input.

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to remove it from the list as a vector eg

`aa3 <- strsplit(my_seq, "")[[1]]`

It would be a good idea to test the number of characters is 25 else it could break eg `testthat::expect_true(nchar(my_seq) == 25)`

To store then print

```
out <- read_aa()
print(out)
```

an overall eg, where you pass in the dataframe

```
read_aa <- function(input) {
  my_seq <- readline(prompt="Enter aa: ")
  testthat::expect_true(nchar(my_seq) == 25)
  aa3 <- strsplit(my_seq, "")[[1]] #splitting aa into separate string
  output <- cbind(new_col = aa3, input) 
  return(output)
}
out <- read_aa(input = df)
print(out)
```

Comment: I can see the output in the console panel but it doesn't save into the df. Sorry, I am new to R. How can that be solved?

Comment: The `print` is only logging it, it doesn't store it. I've added an edit to show how I would store it. You need to assign it back to a variable. If you are running `read_aa` multiple times it may be wise to instead supply df as an input. I'll do an eg